# MSTG-ARCH-3 What means?

Tags: android, mobile, terminology, requirements

In the [OWASP Mobile Application Security Checklist](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mastg/releases/download/v1.5.0/Mobile_App_Security_Checklist_en.xlsx) there is a requirement called MSTG-ARCH-3 which describes:

> "A high-level architecture for the mobile app and all connected remote
> services has been defined and security has been addressed in that
> architecture."

I'm struggling to understand what they meant about that, because in the OWASP site, they just defined the requirement but didn't gave any example of how this works and how to achieve in a proper way.

Does anybody have good insights or references to what is meant with this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is looking for an architecture that includes the mobile application and any services and their connections (e.g. monitoring, auth, payment) used by the application.

The second part requiring that `security has been addressed in that architecture` wants you to show that risk was assessed and security measures are designed into the architecture.  MSTG-ARCH-6 requires a threat model that will detail how risk was assessed in the application and how risk is mitigated by implementing countermeasures.